# AWS serverless application .net Application

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, serverless, aws-toolkit

I am new using AWS Serverless application for .Net . I wanted to know if there is a way in which we can use an existing IAM role while deploying AWS Serverless Application to AWS. And what should be the modification needed in serverless.template.

I am trying to use AWS toolkit for Visual studio to write and deploy to AWS.

Answer (score 0):

While using Visual Studio, you need to provide the appropriate role - `LambdaFullAccess` or custom role which allows you to use it. You can go through it here:

> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/toolkit-for-visual-studio/latest/user-guide/lambda-creating-project-in-visual-studio.html

And for the `serverless.template`: Based on AWS documentation, It's the **CloudFormation** template, if you want to know how to input it? You can go through it here, for example, CloudFormation Lambda Template will show you the default parameters:

> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/quickref-lambda.html